# UIButton image not updating properly when changing states

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uikit

So I'm creating a UIButton and I want to set it to have two separate images for different states (normal and highlighted) but when setting the highlighted property to yes, the highlighted image gets drawn on top of the normal state image, instead of replacing it completely.

Here's my code:

```
    CGFloat size = 50.0;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setFrame:frame];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]forButtonState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"] forButtonState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"] forButtonState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:button];


-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setSelected:YES];
    [sender setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

I've tried using both [button setImage] and [button setBackgroundImage] but the same issue shows up. I've also tried setting the normal_state image to nil before setting isHighlighted to YES but no matter what the normal_state image stays and the highlight_state image gets drawn on top of it.

Comment: Why are you setting the selected state as well?

Comment: For showing two image on single button for one state you use [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: Just try removing that `.jpg` form `[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"] forButtonState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"] forButtonState:UIControlStateHighlighted];` and also in `buttonPressed:` try only one method

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGFloat size = 50.0;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, size, size);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setFrame:frame];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:button];

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [sender setHighlighted:YES];

}
```

You can make button state one at a time i.e. Normal/Highlighted/Selected if you set two state i.e. [sender setSelected:YES];[sender setHighlighted:YES]; at one time. compiler automatically work according to last line i.e.[sender setHighlighted:YES] and make [sender setSelected:NO]; that why it is showing only Highlighted image on button.